# Emacs - setting column mode to be always on

Tags: emacs

How do you turn on `column-number-mode` permanently in `emacs`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$ echo '(setq column-number-mode t)' >>~/.emacs
```

If you prefer menu-based customization, select Options > Show/Hide > Column Numbers, then Options > Save Options.  (This might vary depending on Emacs version.)

Comment: I'm not into the menu-bar, if you are't either you can do `M-x customize-variable` then put in `column-number-mode` then you can toggle the mode on or off.